# Are angular and linear momentums dependant on each other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Or more specificly: Is it possible to have a system where angular momentum is conserved,but not linear?

Answer (score 1):

They are independent. This of a mass roating around a central point in a circular orbit. L is conserved but P is not.

Comment: Why isn't P conserved? If there are no external forces then it should be.

Comment: there is an external force, the centripetal force by the rope, or whatever is making the object's motion circular. v is constantly changing direction, and so is P.